# Method definition issue Java

Tags: java, methods

im currently learning the basics of Java. I currently am having trouble finding out what symbol cannot be found by the compiler. I honestly have no idea what is wrong with my method. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GasVolume {
final static double GAS_CONST = 8.3144621;

double ComputeGasVolume (double gasPressure, double gasTemperature, double 
gasMoles) {
double gasVolume = ((gasMoles * GAS_CONST) * gasTemperature) / gasPressure;

return gasVolume;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
   Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  double gasPressure;
  double gasMoles;
  double gasTemperature;
  double gasVolume;

  gasPressure = 100;
  gasMoles = 1 ;
  gasTemperature = 273;

  gasVolume = computeGasVolume(gasPressure, gasTemperature, gasMoles);
  System.out.println("Gas volume: " + gasVolume + " m^3");
  }
  }
```

When I compile the program, the error I get is:

```
  GasVolume.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
  gasVolume = computeGasVolume(gasPressure, gasTemperature, gasMoles);
              ^
  symbol:   method computeGasVolume(double,double,double)
  location: class GasVolume
  1 error
```

Comment: Hint: See `static`

Comment: Two problems. You can't call an instance method without an instance. Make it `static`. Two you can't switch cases and expect it to work. `ComputeGasVolume` has a capital "C". Look very closely at `gasVolume = computeGasVolume(gasPressure, gasTemperature, gasMoles);`

Comment: For beginners, using an IDE is highly recommended. It helps you avoid simple mistakes like this. Netbeans, Eclipse, IntelliJ are all good options.

Comment: Saw that typo, thanks for pointing that out. Now im getting error: non-static method computeGasVolume(double,double,double) cannot be referenced from a static context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you declared your method as "ComputeGasVolume" and trying to call it as "computeGasVolume". Java is case sensitive. and certainly computeGasVolume has to have "static" in declaration as it is called from static "main" method

Comment: Yup, I completely understand the basic concepts now. Thanks a bunch everyone! Ill accept your answer when im allowed to.

Comment: @Mace Try to understand what static keyword actually does before throwing it on everything, though